# weird,not able to use facebook with android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am making simple app which is using admob to display ads.when i try to load facebook loginview it opens the  background image that i am using in my app.
The weird thing is that if i remove that background(from drawable folder) then it works fine.
Below is the logcat for that.

**W/webcore (  226): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout**

```
    D/dalvikvm(  226): GC freed 4164 objects / 272104 bytes in 75ms
    D/Facebook-WebView(  226): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=297032223671480&scope=publish_stream&type=user_agent&redirect_
    uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
    D/Facebook-WebView(  226): Webview loading URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=297032223671480&display=touch&next=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&ty
    pe=user_agent&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream
    D/Facebook-WebView(  226): Redirect URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=297032223671480&display=touch&next=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&type=user
    _agent&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream
    D/Facebook-WebView(  226): Webview loading URL: http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=297032223671480&cancel=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26err
    or%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpe
    rmissions.request%26app_id%3D297032223671480%26redirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26fbconnect%3D1%26perms%3Dpublish_stre
    am%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1&_rdr
    D/Facebook-WebView(  226): Redirect URL: http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=297032223671480&cancel=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Dac
    cess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissio
    ns.request%26app_id%3D297032223671480%26redirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26fbconnect%3D1%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%26fr
    om_login%3D1&rcount=1&_rdr
    **W/webcore (  226): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout**
    W/InputManagerService(   52): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44e8c320
    D/dalvikvm(  107): GC freed 109 objects / 5224 bytes in 156ms
```

Comment: is there any one who had faced this problem?

Comment: @HHitendra Post some code please

Answer (score 0):

it says "access_denied" in error response, looks like you are not passing app_id when launching the dialog, see documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)

and better to append one more parameter -> display=touch